# Can human males produce milk?

Tags: physiology, gender, milk

Can human males lactate (produce milk) in the manner females can?

According to Wikipedia:

> Spontaneous lactation occasionally occurs in starving men; after World
>   War II, for example, thousands of cases were observed among POWs
>   released from concentration camps. The phenomenon of successful human
>   male breastfeeding has been credibly observed in several cases.
>   However, the cases are not sufficiently documented to allow
>   distinguishing of possible pathologic galactorrhea.

Sources: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Male_lactation#Human_male_lactation
http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=strange-but-true-males-can-lactate&sc=rss

If true, under what conditions can males lactate?

Comment: What makes you skeptical of the existence of galactorrhea in man? For the causes see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactorrhea

Comment: "You can milk just about anything with nipples"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes.**

The medical term for lactation outside of pregnancy and childbirth is [galactorrhea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactorrhea). It has been observed in males<sup>(1)(2)</sup>. In newborns, it is relativity common in both sexes, and is called "witch's milk."<sup>(3)</sup> [Prolactin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolactin) is the hormone associated with lactation and it is secreted by the anterior pituitary gland.<sup>(4)</sup>

The causes are varied. According to the [American Academy of Family Physicians](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2001/0501/p1775.html) some causes are:

> - Medicines, like hormones, antidepressants and blood pressure medicines
> - Herbs, such as nettle, fennel, blessed thistle, anise and fenugreek seed
> - Street drugs, like marijuana and opiates
> - Hormone imbalance
> - Tumors (usually benign), especially tumors of the pituitary gland (say: pit-too-it-tarry), which is in the brain
> - Pregnancy
> - Clothing that irritates the breasts (like scratchy wool shirts or bras that don't fit well)
> - Doing very frequent breast self-exams (daily exams)
> - Stimulation of the breast during sexual activity
>
> Sometimes the cause can't be found.

<sub>(1)Kleinberg, David L., Gordon L. Noel, and Andrew G. Frantz. "[Galactorrhea: A Study of 235 Cases, Including 48 with Pituitary Tumors](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/nejm197703172961103)." New England Journal of Medicine (1977).</sub>

<sub>(2)Finn, James E., and Lester A. Mount. "[Galactorrhea in Males with Tumors in the Region of the Pituitary Gland](http://thejns.org/doi/abs/10.3171/jns.1971.35.6.0723?journalCode=jns)." Journal of Neurosurgery 35.6 (1971): 723-27.</sub>

<sub>(3)Madlon-Kay, DJ. "['Witch's Milk'. Galactorrhea in the Newborn](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3946357)." American Journal of Diseases of Children (1986).</sub>

<sub>(4)PEÑA, KRISTIN S., and JO ANN ROSENFELD. "[Evaluation and Treatment of Galactorrhea](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2001/0501/p1763.html)." American Family Physicians (2001).</sub>

Comment: The list in the answer is for women, not men, according to its source.  Listing "pregnancy" as a reason for a man to produce milk just doesn't make sense.